# Updating email messages via Outlook vs EWS

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Environment: **Outlook 2013** and **Exchange Server 2013**.

Requirement: Programmatically catch incoming email messages and update specific fields.

Question: I was wondering if there are any obvious drawbacks or advantages to developing the above requirement via an **Outlook Add-In** project or via the **EWS API**?

Note: Looks like both methods are feasible, but it seems that I will need to catch more events via **Outlook** as opposed to the **EWS API**.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that Outlook events happen only in the Outlook desktop client in which they are installed, and can be disabled by the end user. So if the user uses Outlook Web App for instance, your events will not be fired. If Outlook is closed, events won't fire. However, and Outlook solution is probably easier to develop, and depending on the scope of your project, the limitations may not be a factor.

For the EWS route, you would want to look into [notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

EWS and OOM are different things. You can read more about EWS in the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) section in MSDN.

Take a look at the series of articles that describe how to catch incoming emails:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)